# Frogs Game Amortized Analysis

Tags: analysis-of-algorithms, amortized-analysis

The game is defined by two integer parameters: n and k.
We are given an array of n sets:
$$S_1, S_2, ...., S_n$$
such that, each of them is a subset of
$\{1, 2, ..., k\}$.
Adversary picks a set $S_i$ in each turn and changes it into an empty set.
the cost that we must paid is a minimal number $t$ such that:
$$S_i \subseteq S_{i-t} \cup S_{i-t+2} \cup ... \cup S_{i-1}$$ or
$$S_i \subseteq S_{i+1} \cup S_{i+2} \cup ... \cup S_{i+t}$$
if there is no such $t$ we must pay:
$$min(i, n-i)$$
can we settle an upper bound on the amortized cost of $n-1$ turns?

Comment: Do you want a bound that holds for all possible arrays, and depends on only $n$ and $k$?  What regime of $k,n$ are you interested in?  Where $k$ is very small compared to $n$?  Where $k$ is comparable to $n$?  If there is no $t$ such that either equation holds, then am I correct to assume that the cost is $+\infty$?  What's the motivation for this question or the context where it arises?  What have you tried?  What is the best bound you have been able to find so far?

Comment: when there is not such $t$, we must paid $min(i, n-i)$. I interest in cases that $k = o(log n)$.

Comment: I'm motivated to this problem because it is very helpfull tool for online algorithm analysis. I fact I want to solve this problem to settle an upper bound on competitive ratio on an online algorithm for chordal graphs coloring.

Comment: Your question does not match your comment.  $\min(i,n-i)$ or $\min(n,n-i)$?  Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: The quantifiers are not clear at all. An adversary gives the array of sets, and also the adversary picks the $i$ in each round, i.e., we have no choice anywhere in this game?